# Не получает экспортировать найденные данные в csv

Tags: python, django, csv

Не получается экспортировать данные в csv.
При нажатии `Download CSV` сохраняет весь html,

[image: весь html]

а требуется только найденные.
Что я не внес еще в `views.py`?

index.html:

```html
{% if response %}
    <h5><a href="{{ response.url }}" download="journal.csv">Download CSV</a></h5>
{% endif %}
```

viwes.py:

```py
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Journal
from django.db.models import Q, Count, Sum


# Create your views here.


def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def BootstrapFilterView(request):
    """ Поиск """
    qs = Journal.objects.all()
    categories = Journal.objects.values('author').distinct().exclude(author__isnull=True)
    title_or_author_query = request.GET.get('title_unit')
    if title_or_author_query is None:
        title_or_author_query = "empty unit"  # Если вернется None ["empty", "unit"]
    lst_vm_query = title_or_author_query.split()

    if request.method == "GET":
        # фильтруем значения

        qs = qs.filter(Q(title__in=lst_vm_query)  # Поиск списоком вм
                       | Q(author__iexact=title_or_author_query.strip())  # Поиск ВМ без учета регистра
                       | Q(title__iexact=title_or_author_query)  # Поиск ИИС без учета регистра
                       )

        hpc_hdd_jt = qs.values_list('HPC_HDD_JT_CAPACITY', flat=True)
        # HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
        # Так как постргресс не принимает тип данных, убираем /n, и преобразуем строки в int()
        # суммируем
        # capacity = sum(map(int, " ".join(filter(None, hpc_hdd_jt)).replace("\n", "").split()))
        capacity = sum(int(float(p)) for p in " ".join(x for x in hpc_hdd_jt if x is not None).replace("\n", "").split())
        # capacity = sum(([int(float(p)) for p in " ".join([x for x in hpc_hdd_jt if x is not None]).replace("/n", "").split()]))

        # суммируем проц, память
        core = qs.aggregate(Sum('HPC_SERVER_CORE_K'))
        ram = qs.aggregate(Sum('HPC_SERVER_RAM'))

        # generate csv file
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="journal.csv"'
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['name', 'HPC_HDD_JT_CAPACITY', 'HPC_SERVER_CORE_K', 'HPC_SERVER_RAM'])

        for obj in qs:  # Add this loop to iterate over the queryset rows and write the data to CSV
            writer.writerow([obj.title, obj.HPC_HDD_JT_CAPACITY, obj.HPC_SERVER_CORE_K, obj.HPC_SERVER_RAM])

        context = {

            'queryset': qs,
            'core': core,
            'ram': ram,
            'capacity': capacity,
            'categories': categories,
            'response': response


        }

        return render(request, "index.html", context)
```